# find {} returns the full filename but I just want the filename without the extension, so index.md would return index instead of index.md

Tags: find, filenames

So I have

```
find . -name \*.md -type f -exec pandoc --filter ./filter1.py -o {}.html {}
```

And notice the `{}.html`. The `{}` returns a filename ending with `.md`, but I want it to just return the filename without the `.md`, so say I have a file named `index.md`, `{}` should return `index`, resulting in a file named `index.html`, rather then resulting in a filename named `index.md.html`.

So how would I go about removing the `.md` within this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-exec` to create a new bash shell, then manipulate `{}` inside the shell by passing it as a parameter (it can be accessed as `$0` in the new shell). You can remove the `.md` filetype ending with parameter expansion:

```
find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec bash -c 'pandoc --filter ./filter1.py -o ${0%md}html' {} \;
```

Comment: ${0} seems to return "bash" and not the filename, that is if I simplify your command down to: `find . -name '*.md' -exec bash -c 'echo ${0}' \;` I get echoed back "bash" three times (I have three .md files).

Comment: Try `$1` instead.

Comment: @JoshJolly I think your original was correct - perhaps @01AutoMonkey  missed the following `{}`? if you use `$1` AFAIK you will need to add a 'dummy' positional parameter e.g. `bash -c 'echo ${1%.md}.html' sh {} \;`

Comment: Ah yes, you're right @steeldriver. @01AutoMonkey - you need to have the `{}` after the bash shell command to pass it in as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

It will work.

For example consider a `.txt` file in a current directory

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec basename \{\} .txt \;
```

Comment: Be careful, it also strips away the directory.

Comment: @orion I edited.