# Manipulate {} return string from find -exec

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, find

I want to do it as efficient as possible in case there will be a lot of files.
What I want is rename all the files I found and remove their suffix.

For example:

```
[/tmp] $ ls -l
a.log
b.log
c.tmp
[/tmp] $ find /tmp -name "*.log" -type f -exec mv {} {%.*} \;
[/tmp] $ ls -l
a
b
c.tmp
```

This doesn't work. If it was a normal bash variable `${var%.*}` would have returned `var` until the last `.`.

Comment: Why don't use [rename](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Omitting extension with find?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61656/omitting-extension-with-find) or [find {} returns the full filename but I just want the filename without the extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185121/22142)

Comment: The issue with `-exec bash ...` is that it will open bash on every file ..

Comment: If you read the answers to those questions and the one below you will learn that `find` is not a shell. You're trying to use _shell parameter expansion_ (which, as the name implies, is shell-specific)  within `find`. It won't work. In your example above you don't even need `find`, a simple `for` loop will do (which btw would allow you to use parameter expansion).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start a shell to use shell parameter expansion operators:

```
find ~/tmp -name '*.log' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    mv -i -- "$file" "${file%.*}"
  done' sh {} +
```

Note that you don't want to do that on `/tmp` or any directory writable by others as that would allow malicious users to make you rename arbitrary `.log` files on the file system¹ (or move files into any directory²).

With some `find` and `mv` implementations, you can use `find -execdir` and `mv -T` to make it safer:

```
find /tmp -name '*.log' -type f -execdir sh -c '
  for file do
    mv -Ti -- "$file" "${file%.*}"
  done' sh {} +
```

Or use `rename` (the perl variant) that would just do a `rename()` system call so not attempt to move files to other filesystems or into directories...

```
find /tmp -name '*.log' -type f -execdir rename 's/\.log$//' {} +
```

Or do the whole thing in `perl`:

```
perl -MFile::Find -le '
  find(
    sub {
      if (/\.log\z/) {
        $old = $_;
        s/\.log\z//;
        rename($old, $_) or warn "rename $old->$_: $!\n"
      }
    }, @ARGV)' ~/tmp
```

But note that `perl`'s `Find::File` (contrary to GNU `find`) doesn't do a safe directory traversal³, so that's not something you would like to do on `/tmp` either.

---

#### Notes.

¹ an attacker can create a `/tmp/. /auth.log` file, and in between `find` finding it and `mv` moving it (and that window can easily be made arbitrarily large) replace the `"/tmp/. "` directory with a symlink to `/var/log` resulting in `/var/log/auth.log` being renamed to `/var/log/auth`

² A lot worse, an attacker can create a `/tmp/foo.log` malicious `crontab` for example and `/tmp/foo` a symlink to `/etc/cron.d` and make you move that crontab *into* `/etc/cron.d`. That's the ambiguity with `mv` (also applies to `cp` and `ln` at least) that can be both *move to* and *move into*. GNU `mv` fixes it with its `-t` (*into*) and `-T` (*to*) options.

³ `File::Find` traverses the directory by doing `chdir("/tmp"); read content; chdir("foo") ...; chdir("bar"); chdir("../..")...`. So someone can create a `/tmp/foo/bar` directory and at the right moment, rename it to `/tmp/bar` so the `chdir("../..")` would land you in `/`.

Comment: Would be nice make it without opening shell every file

Comment: @Nir, that's what the `{} +` form is for. It passes as many files as possible to `sh` so you run as few `sh`s as possible. For the `-execdir` form, you'd still need at least one `sh` per different directory (and some `find` implementations like on FreeBSD would still run one `sh` per file even if there are several matching files in a given directory).

Comment: I didn't know about the `{} +` option. It looks as the best option for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Well, `/tmp` is just an example. Anyway I tried your solution with `rename` but it doesn't do anything: `find . -name '*.log' -type f -execdir rename 's/\.log$/\.bluf/' {} +`. The find command do return the correct files when I execute this command without the `-execdir`

Comment: @Nir, beware some Linux distributions come with a completely incompatible implementation of `rename`. The `perl` one might be called `prename` on your system. Also note that you don't need to escape the `.` in the replacement.

Comment: I tried escape the `.` and without escaping it. I guess my version doesn't support the rename option.

Comment: @Nir, try `rename --version`. If it says `util-linux`, it's not the right `rename`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one-liner:

```
find /tmp -name "*.log" -type f -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv "$f" "${f%.*}"' \;
```

It launches a shell, assigns the {} to a proper variable inside the shell and then applies the string manipulations using the shell syntax.