# find exec - use only partial filename from {}

Tags: find, command

I have following directory structure:

```
├── file1.json
├── file2.json
└── file3.json
```

I want to remove the `.json` suffix. I know the best way would probably be the `rename` command or to use a `for-loop`, but I was wondering if the `find` command can do that too.

For example appending `.json` is simple, I following command:

```bash
find . -type f -name 'file?' -exec mv {} {}.json \;
```

But now I want to reverse the name process, how can I do that with `find`?

Comment: @ChrisDavies oh I don't have any restrictions. I also have no goals to achieve. This is only for learning purposes. In the real world I would use `rename`. But I was thinking about `find` and if I can subtstring the `{}` var :) It doesn't even matter if I use `mv` or `echo` or any other command. That was just the first best example I could come up with^^

Comment: @don_crissti Yeah I know^^ And yeah I have seen [Manipulate {} return string from find -exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406012/515636) and many other posts. But most of them use a `for-loop`. I don't know, I just have the feeling that there has to be a better way to do it^^

Comment: @Pixelbog, you don't have to use a loop, but you do have to use a shell or _something_ to modify the filename. `find` can't do it itself. Using `{} +` with a loop in the shell just optimizes it by starting fewer shell processes.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial process renamed files by appending `.json`. For example `file1` (matching the pattern `file?`) was renamed to `file1.json`. The reverse is more complicated and requires a little shell script processing

```
find . -type f -name 'file?.json' -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%.json}"' _ {} \;
```

This will invoke `sh` for each file found by `find`. Typically a more efficient process can be created for very little increase in complexity:

```
find . -type f -name 'file?.json' -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.json}"; done' _ {} +
```

Both solutions make use the POSIX shell substitution `${var%suffix}`, which returns a value corresponding to `$var` with the literal text `suffix` removed (if possible) from the end of its value.

```
var=hello.txt
echo "${var%.txt}"    # "hello" because ".txt" is removed
echo "${var%.zzz}"    # "hello.txt" because there is no ".zzz" suffix
echo "$var"           # "hello.txt" because the variable itself is unchanged
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the manual is quite clear:

> The string ‘{}' is replaced by the current file name being processed
> [...]

`find` does *not* provide additional placeholders that would manipulate the file name
like `gnu parallel` does with its `{.}`, `{/}` etc... however, there is an alternative to `find` which does: it's called [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) (sometimes `fdfind`) and if you used that one you could run:

```
fd -e json -x mv -- {} {.}
```

`fd -e json` means find files with `json` extension, `-x` stands for "execute" then `{}` and `{.}` are placeholders for file name and respectively file name without extension (same string replacements as `gnu parallel`).

Note that you'll need to quote `{}` (as `'{}'`) in `rc`, `akanga` and older versions of `fish`, and  `{.}` in those plus `csh`, `tcsh`, `zsh -o braceccl`, where `{`/`}` have a special meaning.

Also beware that by default `fd` (contrary to `find`) ignores hidden files (those whose name starts with a `.` or are below a directory whose name starts with a `.` but also those mentioned in `.ignore`/`.gitignore`/`.git/ignore`/`.fdignore`... files; see the `-H`/`--hidden`, `-I`/`--no-ignore`, `-u`/`--unrestricted` options to change that) and those whose name cannot be decoded as UTF-8 (regardless of the locale).